# Retrieving complete file URLs in a browser drop event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I need to retrieve complete file URLS when dropping files onto an html div in Safari (or Chrome). Security precludes a browser from revealing that data in a the DataTransfer api. At most you can retrieve the size and name of the file, but not the system relative path.

Would a Safari or Chrome Extension be appropriate for this? The DataTransfer api allows for files to be dropped, but I would like to accept the drops and pass the URLS on to another process via http post request. I have seen this done in another web extension and would like to replicate the behavior.

Comment: No, it's not possible using an extension. The only solution is to write a separate native OS utility that intercepts the low-level system message on drag'n'drop. Such a utility can communicate with an extension using [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Can you clarify 'native OS utility that intercepts the low-level system message '?

Comment: Writing it will be much more complicated than this description so let's leave it at that.

Comment: One thing I am investigating is if the dragging pasteboard is accessible from an extension, then the data might be accessible there.